# How do I check to see if the text of a jQuery variable contains specific text?

Tags: jquery, html, css

So I have captured the ID of an image in a jquery variable like so:

```
$("#tag img").click(function(e) {       
    var element = $(this).attr("id");
```

How do I then parse the var element?

I would like to put it in an if statement like this:

```
if ( $(element *= 'square' ) {
    $('#tag #view_name').text("Tag with a Square");
}
elseif ($(element *= 'circle' ) {
    $('#tag #view_name').text("Tag with a Circle");
}
```

How do I do that, with the least amount of code possible?

Thanks.

Edit: Oh, and the text I am searching for are the two strings in the single quotes ('square' and 'circle').

Edit: All of the answers below look like they should be working...but they aren't. Here is the other code, so you guys can see if I am missing something:

```
<div id="tag">
        <a href=""><img src="images/square.png" id="square-tag"></a> | 
        <a href=""><img src="images/circle.png" id="circle-tag"></a> |      
        <span id="view_name">Tag with Square</span>
    </div>
```

Edit 3: Ok...it seems that some other jQuery was hijacking that div. All the answers are right. I wish I could mark all of them correct :)

Comment: what exactly is 'text of a JQuery variable' ?

Comment: Basically, I want it to mean 'if the variable contains that string'. If I was checking the attribute str8 from the selector, I could do that...like this: `$("input[name*='man']").val("has man in it!");` So I was trying to figure out how to accomplish that outside of the selector statement.  But it isn't working like this.

Comment: Just use `indexOf` on the text, or whatever you are checking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is similar to `$("input[name*='man']")` selector (example from your comment)

```
var name = $(this).attr("name");
if (name.indexOf('square') >= 0) {
    $('#tag #view_name').text("Tag with a Square");
}
```

Comment: Cool! Do you have a URL that explains this more?

Comment: @marc - There's no reason for 2 IDs in a selector, it's very inefficient :)

Comment: @Nick you are right. I will have to re-arrange a few stuff to fix it. Had the issue of multiple elements (i.e. the exact same span on another page) with the same ID.

Answer (score 3):

From a minimal code standpoint, this would work:

```
$("#tag img").click(function() {  
  if (this.id.indexOf('square')>-1) {
    $('#view_name').text("Tag with a Square");
  } else if (this.id.indexOf('circle')>-1) {
    $('#view_name').text("Tag with a Circle");
  }
});
```

When selecting by ID use *only* the ID, it's a faster selector as well.  I'm doing it this way because of how your question's phrased, for this specific example, it's a bit cleaner to do:

```
$("#tag img[id*='square']").click(function() { 
  $('#view_name').text("Tag with a Square");
});
$("#tag img[id*='circle']").click(function() { 
  $('#view_name').text("Tag with a Circle");
});
```

Comment: Looks like it should work....but it's not agreeing with my code - for some reason. I have updated my original question with more HTML for troubleshooting purposes.

Comment: @marcamillion - Here's a demo with the code, note the added `href` so the page doesn't redirect: http://jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/efEBd/

Comment: Thanks Nick. Got it. Silly me...something else was hijacking that div's click(function()) :|

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
if (element.indexOf("square") != -1)
    $('#tag #view_name').text("Tag with a Square");
else if (element.indexOf("circle") != -1)
    $('#tag #view_name').text("Tag with a Circle");
```

Comment: You must be doing something wrong, because these methods we have all posted shouldn't fail for any reason.

Comment: It works now...my bad. There was another piece of JS that was hijacking that ID.